# IPv6 Host Discovery?

Tags: networking, ipv6, subnet

I am trying to discover all IPv6 hosts on my MASSIVE business network (like a /32 block).

I have an nmap [script](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/targets-ipv6-multicast-echo.html) I think that works but sadly only for my local subnet. Would this work if I changed my subnet to include all LANs?

Do you know any better ways to discover IPv6 hosts?

Answer (score 1):

The script uses the `ff02::1` multicast address. That is the multicast address for all IPv6 nodes on the local link. So you will need to run it on each LAN. There is no equivalent for multiple LANs.

You either have to run this script on each LAN, or you have to use network management tools that get information from the switches and routers in your network.